# Retrieve multiple user objects using latest twitter api with python

Tags: python, twitter

Has the latest version of twitter api removed the ability to retreive multiple user objects with a single call?

If not is it still GetUser function?

If I have a list of user screen names how can I retrieve all the user objects with a single call?

e.g. if the list is :
    users = [user1,user2, user3......user200]

Probably, the developer manual has an answer but I am struggling to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't the users lookup get you what you need?

```
GET users/lookup
```

reference: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

> Return up to 100 users worth of extended information, specified by either ID, screen name, or combination of the two. The author's most recent status (if the authenticating user has permission) will be returned inline.
>
> This method is crucial for consumers of the Streaming API. It's also well suited for use in tandem with friends/ids and followers/ids.

---

in [python-twitter](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/), this is accessed via:

```
def UsersLookup(self, user_id=None, screen_name=None, users=None):
```

source: https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter.py#L3189

> Fetch extended information for the specified users.
>
> Users may be specified either as lists of either user_ids,
>     screen_names, or twitter.User objects. The list of users that
>     are queried is the union of all specified parameters.
>
> The twitter.Api instance must be authenticated.
>
> Args:
>        user_id:
>           A list of user_ids to retrieve extended information.
>           [Optional]
>         screen_name:
>           A list of screen_names to retrieve extended information.
>           [Optional]
>         users:
>           A list of twitter.User objects to retrieve extended information.
>           [Optional]
>
> Returns:
>         A list of twitter.User objects for the requested users

---

Here is some info for "tweepy"

```
""" Perform bulk look up of users from user ID or screenname """
def lookup_users(self, user_ids=None, screen_names=None):
```

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L146